# В квадратном массиве записаны целые числа - найди кол.во элементов диагонали равных пяти и число парных элементов главной диагонали массива

Tags: c, массивы

В квадратном массиве записаны целые числа. Необходимо найти кол.во элементов побочной диагонали равных 5 и число парных элементов главной диагонали массива.

Внизу мой код, который создает массив и сортирует. Как реализовать задачу я не понимаю.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    int main(){
    int i,j,n=5,x[5][5],a[16],tmp;
    puts ("Massive X:\n");


    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
    x[i][j]=rand()%9;
    printf ("[%i]  ",x[i][j]);}
    puts ("");}

    for (j=0;j<5;j++){
    a[j]=x[0][j];}

    for (i=1;i<4;i++){
    a[4+i]=x[i][0];}

    for (i=1;i<4;i++){
    a[7+i]=x[i][4];}

    for (j=0;j<5;j++){
    a[11+j]=x[4][j];}

    puts ("");

    for (i=0;i<16;i++)
    printf ("[%i]  ",a[i]);
    puts ("");

    for (i=0;i<16;i++){
    for (j=15;j>i;j--){

        if (a[j]>a[j-1]){
        tmp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[j-1];
        a[j-1]=tmp;}}}

    for (i=0;i<16;i++){
    printf ("[%i]  ",a[i]);}}
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А зачем вы сортируете? Вам просто надо найти среди всех `x[i][i]` количество чисел, равных 5, и количество четных чисел...

Comment: @Harry, это необходимо выполнить через программу, а не "личным подсчётом" вручную.

Comment: Знаете, если это ваш юмор - то он таки не смешной. Еще раз - зачем вы выполняете сортировку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вся ваша программа. Форматирование постарался выдержать в вашем стиле - чтоб враги ничего не смогли понять.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    int main(){
    int i,j,x[5][5];
    puts ("Massive X:\n");


    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
    x[i][j]=rand()%9;
    printf ("[%i]  ",x[i][j]);}
    puts ("");}

    int even=0,five=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;++i){if(x[i][i]%2==0)++even;
    if(x[i][4-i]==5)++five;}printf("Evens=%d,fives=%d\n",even,five);}
```